# How can a PNP transistor work as Amplifier?

Tags: transistors, amplifier, pnp

I am not understanding the concept of using PNP transistors as amplifiers. Could you please help me in this?

Thanks

Comment: Do you understand how an NPN transistor can work as an amplifier?

Comment: What do you not understand?  Post an example circuit, and explain the parts you do understand, then tell us what you don't understand.  As it is, you have asked for a complete description of an amplifier using  PNP, and that is a bit much.

Comment: Gain will be gm * Zcollector; for silicon, the gm is 0.026/Ic milliAmps, thus at 1mA the gm is 0.026 or 26mA/volt. The Zcollector means *all* the impedances on the collector, computed in parallel: Rout (Vearly sets this), RL to the rail, any parasitic capacitances, and Zload (where C2 connects).

Answer (score 6):

From [Vintage-Radio](https://www.vintage-radio.com/repair-restore-information/transistor_biasing.html).

[image]

**Transistor polarity**

There are two different types of transistor - NPN and PNP. The circuits for the two are similar, however the polarity of the power supply for PNP types is the opposite way around to that for NPN types. With NPN types the emitter is negative, whereas with PNP types it is positive. To anyone familiar with valve circuits or more modern transistor electronics, the power supply to PNP transistors seems to be upside down.

This diagram shows the same common-emitter amplifier circuit using an NPN transistor (a) and a PNP transistor (b). The polarity of the battery and electrolytic capacitors are reversed, but otherwise the circuits are identical.

When carrying out voltage measurements with an analogue meter, you will need to connect the negative probe to the ground rail for the NPN circuit and the positive probe to the ground rail for the PNP circuit. A digital meter will just read positive or negative as appropriate.

Nearly all early transistor radios use germanium PNP transistors.

Comment: Thanks, Mr Transistor!